# C# Pointer arithmetic slower than explicit if

Tags: c#, performance, unsafe

I am currently porting a critbit tree implementation from C to C#, using unsafe C#. I noticed some strange behavior performancewise, that I cannot really explain.

Let's say I have tree-node with exactly two children. As I cannot seem to have an unsafe struct with an array of pointers of itself I would do something like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
    internal unsafe struct CritBitTreeNode
    {
        public byte Type;

        public CritBitTreeNode* Child1;

        public CritBitTreeNode* Child2;

        public int Byte;

        public byte Otherbits;
    }
```

Depending on a calculated direction I want to follow Child1 or Child2 in a loop. So the code looks something like this:

```
while (node->Type == 1)
{
    int direction = CalculateDirection(...)
    node = direction == 0 ? node->Child1 : node->Child2;
}
```

Now I thought that having an if and then accessing the member must be slower than just grabbing the pointer and adding direction to it like this:

```
node = *(&node->Child1 + direction)
```

Turns out my assumption was wrong. My benchmarks compare my algorithm with the default hashset. Changing this one line like this changes the Ratio from a pretty great 0.75 to a pretty bad 1.33 (baseline Hashset Contains). Can anyone explain this to me, why the pointer arithmetic seems to be slower?

The complete source code can be found here (method Contains): https://github.com/TimHeinrich/CritBitTree/blob/master/CritBitTree/UnmanagedCritBitTree.cs

I also tried to reproduce this issue with a microbenchmark, but with no success, actually the pointer arithmetics win there, which is why I assume it has to be something entirely different, like branch predition? Any insight on this is much appreciated!

Comment: If direction is always 0 or 1 then the two children could be in an array of 2. I don't see the need for using unsafe code in your case.

Comment: Yes, no reason to use unmanaged code, but still I would like to understand what is going on

Comment: Is `node` a local variable or a field?  If the latter, the `&` operation likely involves pinning so that the GC doesn't move it.

Comment: Node is a local variable. Looking at the IL Code it does not seem to have anything to do with pinning (at least I would expect a GetPinnableReference around there then). However, it seem to be a few less IL instructions that might explain it here, like there is only one instruction for the if, whereas just calculating the offset seem to be at least 4 instructions